# Camel: How to force enrich() do not invoke aggregate() in case of exception occurred on getting data from resource before version 2.14

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration

In camel 2.14 appeared option `aggregateOnException` to force `aggregate()` invocation.

But we use version 2.8.

In my case such code

```
from("some_route").routeId("enrich")
                .enrich("some_resource_with_useful_info", MyAggregator())
                .multicast().stopOnException()
                    .to("first_client", "second_client");
```

could fail on `"some_resource_with_useful_info"` and I want camel not to invoke `aggregate()` in `MyAggregator`. But it does invoke and there occurred second exception.

Also onException is configured.

```
onException(Exception.class).handled(true).useOriginalMessage()
                    .to(ERROR_LOGGING_ENDPOINT).end();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just detect the exception in `MyAggregator` and propagate it the oldExchange so the Camel error handler can react.

Something a long the lines of doing

```
if (newExchange.getException() != null) {
   oldExchange.setException(newExchange.getException());
   return oldExchange;
}
```